# How can I change the header on the pages?

Tags: images, themes, headers

I'm working with Manufacturer theme and I'm trying to have one header image for each page I have but I can't. Does anyone know how to do it?
I've found that I can change the header here:
[image]
but it will put the same header on all the pages.

I'm very new with wordpress and I'm so lost omg.
Thank you.

Comment: That is two questions.  Please post them separately so that each can be answered and voted upon in its own right.

Comment: Done, thank you for the advice.

Comment: For stuff like this, that is entirely theme specific, it's best to reach out to the theme developer directly as there's not that great a chance you're going to encounter someone here that's worked extensively with that theme.  It's hard to troubleshoot and provide assistance from a screenshot of a third parties theme.